# Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, list

I am getting this error on a webpage, on a Microsoft Report Viewer component:

> An error has occurred during report
>   processing. Local sequence cannot be
>   used in LINQ to SQL implementations of
>   query operators except the Contains
>   operator.

My code:

```
public static IEnumerable GetUrunMiktarliDetayli()
{
    Baglanti();
    List<StokEnvanteriSatiri> urunListesi = new List<StokEnvanteriSatiri>();
    urunListesi = GetUrunListesiDoldur();

    var urunStok = from urunS in urunListesi
                   select new
                   {
                       urunS.AcilisMiktari,
                       urunS.MevcutMiktar,
                       urunS.UrunNo
                   };

    var urunMD = from urun in db.TBLP1URUNs
                 join kategori in db.TBLP1URUNKATEGORIs
                               on urun.KATEGORIID equals kategori.ID
                 join a in urunStok
                        on urun.ID equals a.UrunNo
                 select new
                 {
                     DIGERGIRISLER = a.AcilisMiktari,
                     urun.URUNADI,
                     urun.URUNACIKLAMA,
                     kategori.TREENAME,                         
                     urun.STOKTURU,
                     urun.MARKA,
                     urun.MODEL,
                     urun.URUNTIPI,
                     urun.URUNDURUM,
                     urun.KRITIKSTOKMIKTARI,
                     urun.DEPOADI,
                     urun.YER,
                     urun.RAF,
                     urun.RAFOMRU,
                     KDVDAHILMI = urun.KDVDAHILMI==1 ? "EVET":"HAYIR",
                     urun.KDVORANI,
                     urun.SATFIYAT1,
                     urun.SATFIYAT1BIRIM,
                     urun.TEDFIYAT1,
                     urun.TEDFIYAT1BIRIM,
                     urun.HIZMETYENSURYIL,
                     urun.HIZMETYENSURAY,
                     urun.SATILANMIKTAR,
                     urun.IADEEDILENMIKTAR,
                     urun.KULLANILANMIKTAR,
                     urun.ZAYIMIKTAR,
                     urun.KONSINYECIKISMIKTAR,
                     urun.DIGERCIKISLAR,
                     urun.TEDARIKMIKTAR,
                     urun.IADEALINANMIKTAR,
                     urun.KONSINYEGIRISMIKTAR,                         
                     urun.EN,
                     urun.BOY,
                     urun.YUKSEKLIK,
                     urun.AGIRLIK,
                     urun.BOYUTAGIRLIGI,
                     urun.URUNKAYITTARIHI,
                     urun.GARANTISURESIBITIS,
                     urun.SONGUNCELLEMETARIHI,
                     urun.YENI,
                     urun.TESLIMATSURESI,
                     urun.TEDARIKCISTOKMIKTAR,
                 }
                 ;
    return urunMD;
}

public class StokEnvanteriSatiri 
        {
            private string urunNo;
            private string urunAdi;
            private int acilisMiktari;
            private int toplamTedarikMiktari;
            private int toplamSatisMiktari;
            private int mevcutMiktar;
            private decimal satisFiyati;
            private decimal toplamTutar;
            private string paraBirimi;

            public string UrunNo 
            {
                get { return urunNo; }
                set { urunNo = value; }
            }

            public string UrunAdi 
            {
                get { return urunAdi; }
                set { urunAdi = value; }
            }

            public int AcilisMiktari 
            {
                get { return acilisMiktari; }
                set { acilisMiktari = value;}
            }

            public int ToplamTedarikMiktari 
            {
                get { return toplamTedarikMiktari; }
                set { toplamTedarikMiktari = value; }
            }

            public int ToplamSatisMiktari
            {
                get { return toplamSatisMiktari; }
                set { toplamSatisMiktari = value; }
            }

            public int MevcutMiktar 
            {
                get { return mevcutMiktar; }
                set { mevcutMiktar = value; }
            }

            public decimal SatisFiyati
            {
                get { return satisFiyati; }
                set { satisFiyati = value; }

            }

            public decimal ToplamTutar 
            {
                get { return toplamTutar; }
                set { toplamTutar = value; }
            }

            public string ParaBirimi 
            {
                get { return paraBirimi; }
                set { paraBirimi = value; }
            }

        }
```

This method `GetUrunListesiDoldur()` basically returns a `List<StokEnvanteriSatiri>` list of `StokEnvanterSatiri`, I know the problem is that I am trying to join an in-memory list with an SQL table.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I basically reversed the `join` and it worked

```
var urunMD = from urunStokbilgileri in urunStok
             join urun in db.TBLP1URUNs
                       on urunStokbilgileri.UrunNo equals urun.ID
             join kategori in db.TBLP1URUNKATEGORIs
                       on urun.KATEGORIID equals kategori.ID
             ......
```

Comment: Check the SQL that is actually being executed and make sure you're not pulling all records locally and then filtering them in memory.  It's possible this "works" to retrieve correct results by treating each table as an in-memory collection.  It is also possible that Linq-to-Sql is smart enough to create a proper filtered query here.  I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

You have to force LINQ to evaluate the second join locally. You can do this:

```
var urunMD = (from urun in db.TBLP1URUNs
                 join kategori in db.TBLP1URUNKATEGORIs
                               on urun.KATEGORIID equals kategori.ID).AsEnumerable()
             .Join( [...] )
```

Comment: This will not filter on the database and will bring pull significantly more records from the database than are necessary.

Comment: @Samuel Neff: that is just an assumption... I answered the original question which was "How to join with an in-memory collection".

Comment: an answer that leads the user to do something they definitely shouldn't is not, IMO, a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your `urunMD` query to run in two parts.  Use a `Contains` operator to filter the initial records in `TBLP1URUNs` and then return the database data only.  Then use a separate LINQ-to-Objects query to combine the database data from `TBLP1URUNs` with the in-memory data in `urunStok`.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Neff, I am thinking about this solution.